# adding int to char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I'm trying to parse assembly commands, and there's a certain case I need to generate a random number and add that to a char array.
Example:

```
mov #(random number), r0
```

I have `char* srcOp`

Now I tried doing something like that:

```
int i;
time_t t;

srand((unsigned) time(&t));
i = rand() % 100;
(*srcOp)='#';
// append here i to srcOp . Supopse i is 39 -> srcOp should contain '#39'
```

and now I need to append the value of '`i`' to srcOp, but I either get a runtime error or a compilation error.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MikeCAT The question looks complete - including required result. OP needed to add the string representation of a number 'i' to a string srcOP.  OP has accepted an answer, so a hold doesn't really help anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide on the largest random number you will create.
Size src0p to match the string representation of the largest random number +1 for '#'

sprintf will output a formatted string representation of your number.
Here I have formatted the number with leading zeros.

```
int main (void)
{
    char src0p[6];
    int i;

    i = 999;
    sprintf(src0p, "#%04d", i);

    printf("%s\n", src0p);
}
```

The output looks like this: #0999

Answer (score 0):

I think I have 2 solutions:

```
 (*srcOp)=sprintf("mov #%d, r0",i);
```

Or:

```
(*srcOp)="mov ";
(*srcOp)=strcat((*srcOp),itoa(i));
(*srcOp)=strcat((*srcOp),",r0");
```

One of the above will help you.